# Controlling multiple jquery toggled dropdowns

Tags: jquery

Im currently using three scripts that all do the same thing but I want them all to act smarter. Currently, if I chose to I could show all three drop-down's on the page at the same time stacked on top of each other but I don't want that to happen. How do I adapt my jQuery to check if there is a drop-down already showing, if there is and I've clicked to view another, close that one first before showing the new one.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $(".about").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".about-webly").slideToggle('slow');
    });
});

$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $(".search").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".search-webly").slideToggle('slow');
            $('.search-box').focus();
    });
});

$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $(".submission").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".submit-webly").slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".about").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".search-webly, .submit-webly").hide();
        if($(".about-webly").is(":hidden")){
            $(".about-webly").slideToggle('slow');
        }
    });
    $(".search").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".about-webly, .submit-webly").hide();
        if($(".search-webly").is(":hidden")){
            $(".search-webly").slideToggle('slow');
            $('.search-box').focus();
        }
    });
    $(".submission").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".search-webly, .about-webly").hide();
        if($(".submit-webly").is(":hidden")){
            $(".submit-webly").slideToggle('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

The code can be shortened further putting a little more effort.